# Python Multiprocessing way slower

Tags: python, multithreading

I created a multiproc function which is slower than a monoprocess

```
for n in range(nombre_de_cycles):
    debut = time.time()
    paris.reveil_multiproc(2)
    duree = time.time() - debut
    print((n, duree), end=",")
```

gives :

```
(0, 13.04754900932312),(1, 11.9977388381958),(2, 12.56324291229248),(3, 12.289109945297241),(4, 12.300051927566528),(5, 12.322132110595703),(6, 12.058021783828735),(7, 13.218597173690796),(8, 11.991199016571045),(9, 12.178853034973145),
```

When the monoproc :

```
   for n in range(nombre_de_cycles):
        debut = time.time()
        paris.reveil()
        duree = time.time() - debut
        print((n, duree), end=",")
```

gives

```
(0, 0.19302606582641602),(1, 0.030661821365356445),(2, 0.28160881996154785),(3, 0.04853320121765137),(4, 0.20609474182128906),(5, 0.04185295104980469),(6, 0.20528626441955566),(7, 0.040557146072387695),(8, 0.19860100746154785),(9, 0.11386394500732422),
```

Here are the functions :

```
Class Ville:
    timestamp = 0
    def __init__(self, nb_de_cyclistes, Prestataire):
        self.timestamp =0

    def reveil(self):
        self.timestamp += 1
        list(map(lambda cycliste :cycliste.avancer(self.timestamp), self.cyclistes))

    def faire_avancer(cycliste):
        cycliste.avancer(Ville.timestamp)

    def reveil_multiproc(self, n_jobs=1):
        import multiprocessing
        self.timestamp += 1
        Ville.timestamp = self.timestamp
        pool            = multiprocessing.Pool(n_jobs)
        pool.map(Ville.faire_avancer, self.cyclistes)
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Creating and managing the multiple processes takes time, in this case more time than it takes to simply run your code serially.

Comment: Yes but even for a list of a hundred thousands, the performance are so bad !?

Comment: check your cpu usage.  This could be a case where the workers are being bottlenecked by communication with the main thread.  You should ideally see 2 threads at 100% usage

Comment: Updating an attribute value (which is what I assume `avancer` is doing, takes 10s of nanoseconds. Starting a new process takes a couple of milliseconds, hundreds of times slower than the task you want the process to do in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing is not a 1-size-fits-all solution. You incur significant overhead with your solution to do very little work.

You have the overhead of: Creating 2 worker processes, splitting `self.cylistes` into chunks, serializing it with `pickle`, and using IPC to send it to the subprocess. All this to simply call `cycliste.avancer()` which appears to do very little work.

Having a large list of hundreds of thousands of items is trivial and means nothing when we can't see how much work you're doing in `avancer()`. The more items you have in here will actually most likely slow down the multiprocessing approach because it's unlikely you've implemented optimizations for `pickle` performance.

You need to learn how to use Python's profiling tools (ex: cProfile, line_profiler) before making premature optimizations.

Use `multiprocessing` when you have long-running, CPU-intensive tasks that do not spend most of their time waiting on IO. If each call to `avancer()` took 30 seconds to run, then you would see much better performance with `multiprocessing` then without it.